# Separate indices for UVs and vertexes

Tags: android, opengl-es, indexing, vertex

When creating your buffers for OpenGL on Android, is there any way to use different indexes for your UVs than for your vertexes?

For instance, if you have 5000 vertexes but 12000 UVs and don't want to have to duplicate your vertexes just for each unique UV vertex pair.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining vertex arrays with textures in OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285492/combining-vertex-arrays-with-textures-in-opengl)

Answer (score 1):

Not in ES 1 — OpenGL historically considers a vertex to be a position and/or a texture coordinate and/or a colour, etc. There's no level of dereferencing that would allow you to build a compound vertex from a separate position and texture coordinate.

In ES 2 you can supply your own vertex shader which, on most hardware, can sample textures. You can therefore achieve something a lot like what you want by packing the arrays you want to index into textures and passing indices as vertex attributes.

Comment: Although your ES2 workaround is a nice idea it would be extremely inefficient and cumbersome, compared to just duplicating the vertices at texture seams.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with cumbersome but I absolutely agree that it'd  be significantly less efficient than just duplicating vertices in all but the most artificial of edge cases.